# How can I fix heap inspection security vulnerability in the following line of code?

Tags: security, heap-memory

Checkmarx tool found heap inspection vulnerability in the following line of code.

private String redisAuthKey;

Comment: More details, please.  What programming language?  What's the context of the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.